# Align UI element to gameObject in 2D

Tags: unity, unityscript

I have a 2d game where I want to display UI element perfectly aligned to specific gameObjects.

I have an ortographic camera and I used to `Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint()` function giving it the gameobject position modified, for instance, by +1 on X component to get the UI element on its perfect right.

My problem is that the element is not on the gameObject's perfect right, but sensibly above. See this schema:

Expectation:

G -> UI element

Reality:

---> UI element
G

I tried also to use the `WorldToViewportPoint()` but it's not giving the desired result.
So, I think this is the right way to go but I can't guess what I'm missing.
Any clue?

**EDIT**:
After a little bit more observations it seemed that the UI element alignment depends somehow on it's distance from the center of the screen (of the camera viewport I guess), so that if the gameObject is below half height the UI element y position won't be on the perfect right but slightly below it and if above half heigth will be slightly above the perfect right. Same for x coordinate. Is there a way I could control this?

Comment: If I am correct I think that you are using a script to manipulate some UI element in a canvas which is set to overlay the camera image. Instead you can create a canvas as a child of a game object and set the render mode to world space. This draws whatever is in the canvas at the point the game object is and doesn't overlay the camera. So you can freely move this UI element around using the game object and can even save it as a prefab (I did this for a pop up to state the gained points).


http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/HOWTO-UIWorldSpace.html

Comment: I leaked details. I am currently using a prefab with a canvas on it. The canvas has a child which position is set to be gameObject pos.x +1. The point is that even if I dont specify it in my script also the y position is adjusted (for what I was able to observe) according to its distance from the center of the screen. Well, reading again what you said, I did not try to set the prefab canvas world space. I will try it and see changes. Will update. Thanks!

Comment: If it does work let me know and I can write an answer, if not I can send you the prefab I have made and you can see if that helps

Comment: @Malrig I managed to test it and it works greatly! As your link kindly states all you have to do is deal with scale factor to size every element properly. Please post it as an answer so I can upvote and accept it. Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the [render mode of the canvas to world space](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/HOWTO-UIWorldSpace.html) allows you to manipulate the UIElement as if it was a normal gameobject instead of overlaying it onto the screen.
[image]  [image]

This allows the position, scale etc to be set directly and the position of the camera to have no effect on it.